# R - Plot Only Text

Tags: string, r, text, plot

Curious how one might create a plot with only text information. This will essentially be a "print" for the plot window.

The best option I've found so far is the following:

```
  library(RGraphics)
  library(gridExtra)

    text = paste("\n   The following is text that'll appear in a plot window.\n",
           "       As you can see, it's in the plot window",
           "       One might imagine useful informaiton here")
    grid.arrange(splitTextGrob(text))
```

[image]

However, one doesn't have control (as far as I can tell) over font type, size, justification and so on.

Comment: you don't need `grid.arrange` or `gridExtra`, simply `grid.draw()`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using base graphics. First you'll want to take away all of the margins from the plot window:

```
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
```

And then you'll plot an empty plot:

```
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
```

Here's a guide to what's going on here (use `?plot.default` and `?par` for more details):

- **ann** - Display Annotoations (set to FALSE)
- **bty** - Border Type (none)
- **type** - Plot Type (one that produces no points or lines)
- **xaxt** - x axis type (none)
- **yaxt** - y axis type (none)

Now to plot the text. I took out the extra spaces because they didn't seem to be necessary.

```
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste("The following is text that'll appear in a plot window.\n",
                             "As you can see, it's in the plot window\n",
                             "One might imagine useful informaiton here"), 
     cex = 1.6, col = "black")
```

[image]

Now to restore the default settings

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Also helpful, here's a link to tips to implement different font/typefaces here too: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/parameters.html
- Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, to add info on right and left justify in the text(...) function: "adj = 1" => left justify, "adj = 0" => right justify, "adj = NULL" (the default) => center

Comment: Re Center Adjustment, I was mistaken above. Center adjustment is "adj = 0.5"

Answer (score 29):

You could use `annotate` in `ggplot2` like

```
library(ggplot2)
text = paste("\n   The following is text that'll appear in a plot window.\n",
         "       As you can see, it's in the plot window\n",
         "       One might imagine useful information here")
ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, size=8, label = text) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

And you can of course remove the plot margins, axes, etc. to have just the text

Answer (score 8):

Here's a handy example to play with too:

```
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')

text(x = 0.34, y = 0.9, paste("This is a plot without a plot."), 
     cex = 1.5, col = "black", family="serif", font=2, adj=0.5)

text(x = 0.34, y = 0.6, paste("    Perhpas you'll:"), 
     cex = 1.2, col = "gray30", family="sans", font=1, adj=1)
text(x = 0.35, y = 0.6, paste("Find it helpful"), 
     cex = 1.2, col = "black", family="mono", font=3, adj=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read up on `?par` .  There is limited capability to select the font type via the `family` and `font` arguments.