# R convert string to image

Tags: r, image, converters

I'm having a dataframe  df <- as.dataframe(matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 1)), where df$text has a set of text strings.

I want to convert each one of df$text values, to image, and export it as image.

I tried to export each df$text[i] as .txt file, then as .pdf, and afterwards as image, but in that case I get an A4 dimensioned image which has the text string inside. What I want is to have just an image which will be covered 100% from the text string.

Is there any related function for converting directly a text string into an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base R plotting.

For instance you could create a function `textPlot` that will plot your string and save it. Then you could call it for each rows of your dataset:

```r
textPlot <- function(plotname, string){
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  pdf(paste0(plotname, ".pdf"))
  plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
  text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste(string), cex = 4, col = "black", family="serif", font=2, adj=0.5)
  dev.off()
}
```

If you want a deeper understanding of what's going on, please look at [R - Plot Only Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918985/r-plot-only-text)

Then, calling `textPlot('mytext', 'Hello World')` saves the image `mytext.pdf` in the working directory: [image: Output image with text]

Comment: Is there anyway to have the text covering the 100% of the exported pdf? thank you a lot

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You can increase the `cex` value in the `text()` function to have a bigger string. But it won't adapt to your string length, unless you write it yourself (you can for instance set the `cex` value depending on your string length as a workaround).

Comment: Thank you, increasing the cex value along with a crop function, should do the trick I need, in order to produce small images from text